# Why was my question closed when there are 88k+ that also ask for the "best way" to do something?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Yesterday I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67311994/1376127) (which I have since [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67311994/revisions)). It has been closed as opinion-based.

Before my edit, I asked, "what is the best way to do X?" I thought this would be acceptable because there are [88k+ non-closed questions that ask for the "best way" to do something](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22What+is+the+best+way+to%22+closed%3Afalse+is%3Aquestion), many very highly upvoted. There is also [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348662/1376127) in which answers largely view such questions as not necessarily opinion-based.

Since then, I have edited to just ask "how to do X," but because I don't understand which part of the original part was unacceptably opinion-based, I am not sure if I have adequately addressed the concerns of users who voted to close.

I put a lot of effort into researching options and asking a good question, and am worried that because what I am asking about may not be possible or could be considered "bad design," it influenced users' votes to close the question.

Comment: Policies change over years. Did you check the dates when those questions you reference were written?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there are still many thousands of results for the last few years (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22What+is+the+best+way+to%22+closed%3Afalse+is%3Aquestion+created%3A5y) and the meta discussion is from about 3 years ago. Have the policies changed in the last 3 years?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The policies have changed. That being said, your edit does make it less opinion-based, which is a good thing.

Comment: don't take the existence of non-closed questions as an indication that those questions are necessarily acceptable. We get far more incoming questions than we have users to curate them, so frequently questions that should be closed slip through.

Comment: Time is relative :)

Comment: @anky Yup, and it depends on scale ;)

Comment: It's best... I mean, it's advisable to write questions without red herrings. Keep the language as neutral as possible. Quality on Stack Overflow is pretty much a built-in demand, so there is no need to ask for "the best". Asking for it won't stop someone from posting a really poor answer, which quality voting should show. You should be happy when you get an answer that you can understand, works and 6 months from now when looking back at the code you can still explain to yourself. The best? Who cares. *Good enough.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only thing in your span of control is to adjust ***your*** question to be less off-topic and to ask less about "best way".  Let's say that this is a trigger word for content curation purposes; seeing someone ask about the "best" way to do something is very much more often than not the case that someone is looking for an opinionated question.

Your question doesn't appear to do that anymore, so I'd cast a reopen vote.

I would encourage you to leave the other noise about "well others do it too" aside; just because others have done it in the past doesn't mean it's OK to do it going forward.  History has taught us this lesson time and time and time again and it's about time one starts to accept that what was once overlooked if not tolerated in one bygone era is now unacceptable in this modern era.

Comment: I find "the best way" to be more commonly used for "just do my homework and stop asking for stupid clarifications - talk to my teacher if you care" than true opinions... But that does not in any way make "the best way" less of a trigger word.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  It has a synonym: "best practices".  The philosophy between both is pretty simple:  "Let me just do what everyone else is doing so I don't have to exert as much energy in trying something different that could also fail."  Like I preach to students, writing code is *easy*; problem solving is the reason that you're brought onto the team.